# How do I get the name of the database to which my table belongs?

Tags: mysql

My query is `"select column_name,table_name from information_schema.columns"`.  This query returns a number of columns and tables.  Now, I want to determine the name of the database that corresponds to the returned table names.  How do I accomplish this?

Comment: How are you even running such a query without knowing the database name in the first place when initializing the connection?

Comment: I've clarified the question for him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysql> describe information_schema.columns;
+--------------------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG            |
| TABLE_SCHEMA             | <=== this one (schema == database)
| TABLE_NAME               |
| COLUMN_NAME              |
.......
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select database();
```

Is that it? The current schema?